# How to make a 3D array out of a 2D array, along the rows?

Tags: numpy

I have a 2D array that looks like this:

```
>>> X
array([[10, 15],
       [20, 25],
       [30, 35],
       [40, 45],
       [50, 55],
       [60, 65],
       [70, 75],
       [80, 85],
       [90, 95]])

>>> X.shape
(9, 2)
```

My goal is to make a new 3D array with 3 steps for every row:

```
>>> Y
array([[[10, 15],
        [20, 25],
        [30, 35]],

       [[20, 25],
        [30, 35],
        [40, 45]],

       [[30, 35],
        [40, 45],
        [50, 55]],

       [[40, 45],
        [50, 55],
        [60, 65]],

       [[50, 55],
        [60, 65],
        [70, 75]],

       [[60, 65],
        [70, 75],
        [80, 85]],

       [[70, 75],
        [80, 85],
        [90, 95]]])

>>> Y.shape
(7, 3, 2)
```

I'd like to know if there are any simple way to do this, without using loops.

Comment: I've provided two concise solutions below, one using Pandas, and one using pure numpy (both with no loops). Please choose the one you want (preferrably the numpy one) ;)

Comment: @richardec Thank you for your comment and answer!  I've never heard of  the function!

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty awesome. Did you see my pandas answer? It might be useful to you sometime, @maynull.

Comment: I like how pandas, numpy and list comprehension smoothly work altogether. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I dearly love the integration among them as well. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure numpy solution would be to use [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

new_a = sliding_window_view(a, window_shape=(3,2)).reshape(7, 3, 2)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_a
array([[[10, 15],
        [20, 25],
        [30, 35]],

       [[20, 25],
        [30, 35],
        [40, 45]],

       [[30, 35],
        [40, 45],
        [50, 55]],

       [[40, 45],
        [50, 55],
        [60, 65]],

       [[50, 55],
        [60, 65],
        [70, 75]],

       [[60, 65],
        [70, 75],
        [80, 85]],

       [[70, 75],
        [80, 85],
        [90, 95]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to do with Pandas, using [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
new_a = np.array([w.to_numpy() for w in df.rolling(3) if len(w) == 3])
```

Output:

```
>>> new_a
array([[[10, 15],
        [20, 25],
        [30, 35]],

       [[20, 25],
        [30, 35],
        [40, 45]],

       [[30, 35],
        [40, 45],
        [50, 55]],

       [[40, 45],
        [50, 55],
        [60, 65]],

       [[50, 55],
        [60, 65],
        [70, 75]],

       [[60, 65],
        [70, 75],
        [80, 85]],

       [[70, 75],
        [80, 85],
        [90, 95]]])
```